# What's the VA property in the Photoshop text box?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I get the text property for a text box in the Photoshop provided below.

[image]

Does anyone know whats the `VA` property in the info box?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows some *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; document what you found when searching the Internet or manual. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the use of "VA" is used as merely a *visual* to show the space between the V and the A. "VA" doesn't actually represent anything as far as I'm aware, it's not an acronym -- unless *maybe* for "visual adjustment"?? But I doubt that. `:)`

Comment: What's the property for the    A with an underscore?

Comment: @Scott  Do you also know what is the `A underscore` mean in the menu tab?

Comment: I believe it's Baseline Shift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called Tracking. Tracking (sometimes called letterspacing), controls the consistent space between letters across a block of text, and affects a word or text block overall. Here's a helpful image from Adobe Help website:

[image]

Comment: If you mouse over the "VA" icon an explanation pops up: "Set the tracking for the selected characters".

Comment: What's the property for the    A with an underscore?

Comment: Please don't ask separate questions in the comments section. And as was mentioned above, you can hover over any item in PS to get an explanation pop-up.

Comment: Do you also know what is the `A underscore` mean in the menu tab?

Comment: I know, but as I mentioned please avoid asking separate question in the comments section.